# Alias a custom Ruby Hash class

Tags: ruby, hash, subclass

I'm writing an application that stores contest results of running a bunch of metrics. The results have these constraints:

- A key `"dq_reasons"` refers to an array of strings
- All other keys default to the Float `0.0`

I like to make these constraints explicit using a custom `ContestResult` class. I want this class to be a `Hash`. I can subclass:

```
MyThing = Class.new(OtherThing)
```

but I [heard](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes) subclassing core Ruby classes has downsides. What are my other options? How can I set up a class instance to be a Hash with a default value and preset a `"dq_reasons"` key to be an empty Array?

Current attempt:

```
class ContestResult < Hash
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@data, :[], :[]=, :each
  def initialize(lyst)
    @data = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 0.0}
    @data["dq_reasons"] = []
    lyst.each {|li| @data[li]}
  end
  def inspect
    @data
  end
end
```

Current functionality:

```
c = ContestResult.new([1,2,3])
# => {"dq_reasons"=>[], 1=>0.0, 2=>0.0, 3=>0.0} 
c[4] # => 0.0
c[3] = 34.5
c # => {"dq_reasons"=>[], 1=>0.0, 2=>0.0, 3=>34.5, 4=>0.0}
```

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you can do

```
h = {"dq_reasons"=>[]}
```

and subsequently call [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) on that. You can provide it with a default value.

```
h.fetch(4, 0.0)
```